# How can i print the absolute path to the oldest file modification date in the directory “/ path / to / directory /” including subdirectories?

Tags: linux, shell, rhel

I am using RHEL. How can i print the absolute path to the oldest file modification date  in the directory “/ path / to / directory /”  including subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
print -r '/ path / to / directory /'**/*(-DOm[1]:P)
```

Note that the `/ path / to / directory /` directory itself is not considered.

Modification times are considered after symlink resolution, and with `:P` all symlinks in path components are expanded as if by using `realpath()`. Symlinks to directories themselves are *traversed* by the recursive descent (change `**` to `***` if you want that).

If you want to limit to *regular* files only (still after symlink resolution), change to:

```
print -r '/ path / to / directory /'**/*(-D.Om[1]:P)
```

If you want to ignore all symlinks, change to:

```
print -r '/ path / to / directory /'**/*(D.Om[1])
```

With `sh` and recent GNU utilities, you could do the equivalent of the latter one with:

```
find '/ path / to / directory /' -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
  sort -zn |
  head -zn 1 |
  cut -zf2- |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```